# Calculate the storage capacity of this disk in GB

Tags: computer-architecture

A disk pack has 12 platters ( plates) having 2048 tracks on every surface. 
It can store 1024 bytes per sector ( assume each track has 512 sectors). Calculate the storage capacity of this disk in GB.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but we're not here to do simple calculations for you. First, look up the definitions of the terms you don't understand in the standard resources (textbooks, Wikipedia, etc.). They really aren't difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I wrong in assuming this is just a simple math problem?

12 * 2048 = number of tracks overall which is 24576

each track has 512 sectors, so 24576 * 512 = 12582912 is your overall sectors.

Then you have 1024 bytes per sector, so 1024 * 12582912 = 12884901888 bytes of data

converting that to gigabytes is 12.8849.. GB

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the accepted one, i'd suggest checking over the rules again though because these types of questions generally aren't acceptable AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, it's just a trivial calculation based on knowing what the various terms in the question mean. As you say, the question isn't really appropriate here, and it's best not to answer such questions.